# codedeploy erases content from directory not affected by deploy

Tags: aws-code-deploy

I have 2 private repositories on GitHub for 2 different websites.  Both websites run off the same set of auto-scaling servers on Amazon (EC2).  I use CodeDeploy to pull the repositories from GitHub and deploy them to the servers, one at a time.  This nearly works perfectly.

The issue is that when I deploy one website, the files from the other website are completely erased.  Not the folder structure, just the files.

One webisite deploys to /var/www/website1 while the other deploys to /var/www/website2 .  The appspec files are:

```
version: 0.0
os: linux 
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/website1/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: /beforeinstall.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: /afterinstall.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

And

```
version: 0.0
os: linux 
files:
  - source: /
    destination: /var/www/website2/
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: /beforeinstall.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
  AfterInstall:
    - location: /afterinstall.sh
      timeout: 300
      runas: root
```

When I deploy "website1", it erases all files from "website2", and vice versa.  I have no idea why.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Before Install for the App (website1)

```
#/bin/bash
sudo service php-fpm stop
sudo service nginx stop
sudo yum -y update
rm /var/www/app -Rf
rm /usr/share/nginx/html/status.php -Rf
```

After Install

```
#/bin/bash
chown app:app /var/www/app/* -Rc
#
find /var/www/app/public_html/files/uploads -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
#
cd '/var/www/app'
su app -c 'composer update'
mv /var/www/fairwarning_app/status.php /usr/share/nginx/html/status.php
#
sudo service php-fpm start
sudo service nginx start
```

Before Install for the API (website2)

```
#/bin/bash
sudo service php-fpm stop
sudo service nginx stop
sudo yum -y update
rm /var/www/api -Rf
```

After Install

```
#/bin/bash
chown api:api /var/www/api/* -Rc
#
cd $'/var/www/api'
su api -c 'composer install'
su api -c 'composer update'
#
sudo service php-fpm start
sudo service nginx start
```

Comment: Can you please do the deployments again and include a print out of your deployment logs? Don't include the agent logs, but the deployment script logs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployments-view-logs.html

Comment: Can you also post the content of `beforeinstall.sh` and `afterinstall.sh` for both websites?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with Windows Server, IIS and .NET application. I don't have `beforeinstall` or `afterinstall` If I just deploy 1 app multiple times, it works perfectly.

Comment: @AnkitSharma Yes, I have added them.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like AWS CodeDeploy doesn't support simultaneous deployments on the same deployment group. You can track progress and [discussion of the issue](https://github.com/aws/aws-codedeploy-agent/issues/185#issuecomment-418197184) on their github issue tracker.